# Priority Queue Implementation using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, collections, priority-queue

Please help me to understand the below-highlighted code block.

```
public class PriorityQueue {
    
    int[] items = new int[10];
    
    int count;

    public void enqueue(int i) {

            int j;
            
            for(j= count-1;j >= 0; j--)
            {
                
                
                if(items[j] > i  )
                {
                    items[j+1] =items[j];
                }
                else
                break;

            }

            System.out.println("J Value-->"+j); 
            **items[j+1] = i;**
        
            count++;
            
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
            System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

After for loop how the value of 'J' is getting calculated.

Comment: It's not being calculated after the loop, it's the loop index.  It'll have whatever value it had when the loop exited.

Comment: It is defined outside the loop `int j;`. Initially its value is 0 (zero value). In the loop its value is `count-1` which keeps reducing by 1 `j--`. Loop will run till j=0, on the j=0 loop in the end of j--, its value is now -1 and exits the loop. As it is defined outside the for loop scope it still has the value

Comment: The value of `j` depends on the values stored in array `items`. Without further details on the conditions these values must satisfy, and the role of `count`,  answering your question seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not compile because you have some `**` characters...

But `j` starts at `count - 1` and decreases by 1 in every loop iteration. You only use `j + 1` however.